# Jersey - Is there a way to instantiate a Per-Request Resource with parameters?

Tags: java, rest, resources, jersey, dropwizard

Suppose I have this class:

```
@Path("/test")
public class TestResource{

   private TestService testService;

   public TestResource(TestService testService){
      this.testService = testService;
   }

   @GET
   public String getMessage(){
      return testService.getMessage();
   }


}
```

Then, I want to register it with Jersey. One would do:

```
 TestService testService = new TestServiceImpl();
 resourceConfig.register(new TestResource(testService));
```

But the problem is that approach makes a single instance of TestResource. I want to make an instance per request. So, Jersey has a way of doing this:

```
 TestService = new TestServiceImpl();
 resourceConfig.register(TestResource.class);
```

That is great! But it doesn't let me to pass instantiation parameters to its constructor.

On top of this, I'm using DropWizard which also doesn't let me access all the methods from the ResourceConfig (but I checked its documentation and didn't find any method that let me pass parameters)

So I was wondering if there is a way of achieving this.

Thanks!

PS: I know I can get away with this using Spring or Guice (or my own instance provider) and injecting my classes, but I don't want to do that (of course I'll do it if it's the only way)

Comment: If you're using Dropwizard 0.8.x Jersey 2.x comes with HK2 (a DI framework) which is pretty easy to use. All you really need to do is register an `AbtractBinder` and bind the `TestService`. If you're using Jersey 1.x, there is an `InjectableProvider` (probably will use a subclass) you can use to provide injectable objects.

Comment: Thanks, but I want a Non-DI solution. For me, if an object depends on another object (or abstraction) needs to be constructed with that object. I want to avoid the whole idea of having an object (i.e. the Spring Context) which has all the knowledge of the other objects in the application. Obviously I use DI when needed, but I prefer avoiding it.

Comment: As per jersey documentation "JAX-RS resources are managed in per-request scope by default which means that new resource is created for each request."  https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e1851

Comment: Yeah I understand that, but there are two ways of registering a resource. In one of them, I need to pass an instance of an object. It doesn't make any sense in a per-request context.
In other words, if Jersey has to instantiate a resource for every request, it has to know how to instantiate it (what parameters to pass). If the resource has a constructor without parameters, there will be no problem.

Comment: Unless Jersey does some Reflection stuff...

Answer (score 1):

As @peeskillet has mentioned, jersey 2.x is tightly coupled with HK2 and it seems that it's the only way to pass a service to it.

```
@Singleton
@Path("/test")
public class TestResource {

   private TestService testService;

   @Inject
   public TestResource(TestService testService){
      this.testService = testService;
   }

   @GET
   public String getMessage(){
      return testService.getMessage();
   }
}
```

And this is how you register:

```
environment.jersey().register(new AbstractBinder(){
   @Override
   protected void configure() {
      bind(TestServiceImpl.class).to(TestService.class);
      // or
      bind(new TestServiceImpl()).to(TestService.class);
   });
environment.jersey().register(TestResource.class);
```