# "Publish" object through http

Tags: java, jersey, jetty, jax-rs

I have an object with state and non-serializable fields, like threads, and I would to invoke functions on it like one would do it through RMI but through http. I don't want to scale and I am in an isolated network. I am currently using Jetty, like this:

```
public class ObjectHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    MyStatefulObject obj;

    public void handle(String target, Request baseRequest, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {


        String action = request.getParameter("action");

        switch (action) {
            case "method1":
                obj.method1(request.getParameter("some-parameter"));
                break;
            case "method2":
                obj.method2(request.getParameter("some-other-parameter"));
                break;
        }
        baseRequest.setHandled(true);
    }
}
```

which is kind of weird. I would like to use something like Servlets, and use the different methods to tell apart the action to do, or use JAX-RS to use the calling url to tell apart the action to do. But both of those methods are stateless, that is, I cannot pass an object to a servlet, and, at least with jersey, the construction was made with the class, not with and instance of it, so I could not control the construction of the `MyStatefulObject` object. So, is there a library for, let's say, annotate an object and pass it to a server instance and start listening to requests? I would like to make something like this:

```
@Path("/")
public class MyStatefulObject {


    MyStatefulObject(Parameter param1, Param) {
        //some building stuff
    }
    @POST
    @Path("/path1")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON  + "; charset=UTF-8")
    void method1(Parameter param) {}

    @POST
    @Path("/path2")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON  + "; charset=UTF-8")
    Object method2(Parameter param) {
          return new Object();
    }
```

}

while outside I would have:

```
    Server server = new Server(8081);
    server.setHandler(new MyStatefulObject(param));
    server.start();
    server.join();
```

Is there a library that makes me able to do that? as I say before, I don't want to scale (this is running in a small network) and there is no security concerns. I just want to "publish" an object.

Comment: You could create your stateful object in other parts of the application and have it as a static field in the Jersey controller class.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, Jersey does allow stateful objects to be published, using the ResourceConfig class with an object (as opposed with a Class, which is the use I found more frequently). Funny cause in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30215676/jersey-is-there-a-way-to-instantiate-a-per-request-resource-with-parameters) they want to do the exact opposite. We simply register an object in the ResourceConfig.

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.net.URI;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.jetty.JettyHttpContainerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

@Path("calculator")
public class Calculator {

    int i = -1;

    public Calculator(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("increment")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String increment() {
        i = i + 1;
        return "" + i;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
        resourceConfig.register(new Calculator(10));
        Server server = JettyHttpContainerFactory.createServer(new URI("http://localhost:8080"), resourceConfig);
        server.start();
    }
}
```